# cURL equivalent of cfhttpparam?

Tags: php, curl, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have a working call to an API using Coldfusion and cfhttp as follows:

```
<cfhttp url="http://api.domain.com/api/proxy.cfc" method="post" result="httpResult" charset="UTF-8">
  <cfhttpparam type="url" name="method" value="apiauth"/>
  <cfhttpparam type="url" name="argumentCollection" value="#jsData#"/>
</cfhttp>
```

The #jsData# is a json string representing an array of data.

What I'm having problems with us the

```
<cfhttpparam type="url" name="method" value="apiauth"/>
```

using cURL.  If I append it to the URL as:

```
http://api.domain.com/api/proxy.cfc?method=apiauth
```

I get a response of:  302 Moved Temporarily

In PHP I've created my array as $remoteArray (and that data works fine, so the issue is not there) and I've tried this as my CURL:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://api.domain.com/api/proxy.cfc',
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
                'method' => 'apiauth',
                'argumentCollection' => json_encode($remoteArray)
        )
));
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
```

but it doesn't work (probably because method=>apiauth isn't a post field - it's a URL param - but I get a 302 if I actually put it in the URL.

**SOLVED** - the $remoteArray *did* have an error in it. Originally the $apiauthkey, $apicomponent and $apimethod were defined outside of the array.  Once they were added into the array for json encoding it worked.  Here's house the $remoteArray was built:

```
$remoteArray = array(
  "apiauthkey" => "$apiauthkey",
  "apicomponent" => "$apicomponent",
  "apimethod" => "$apimethod",
  "apiarguments" => array(
    'address_1'=>"test 1",
    'address_2'=>"test 2",
    'city'=>"new york",
    'email'=>"user@domain.com",
    'first_name'=>"test fname",
    'last_name'=>"test lname",
    'ph_num'=>"2155551212",
    'state'=>"NY",
    'zip'=>"90210",
    'rbpid' => $rbpid,
    )
);
```

Once the nested array was setup properly it works fine with cURL.  Thanks to those who responded!

Comment: it might need to be a `header` of `application/json` and a `body` of `value="#variables.jsData#"` as the `cfhttpparam `

Comment: what does the structure of you json look like?  Also in some of my auths calls I loop through and create a `<cfhttpparam>` for each argument. Also you might want to qualify the `type` parameter in your `<cfhttpparam>`.  I cut up an example of what I am talking about if it will help...(not as an official answer mind you).

Comment: Ah! you got it.  See all you needed to do was post here and you figured it out.  I have done that once or twice myself :D .  Then make yours the 'answer' and mark it as solved :)

Answer (score 1):

Not an official answer just a structural example for the OP to reference because of the PHP crossing over:

fieldType can be `url` or `formfield`

method can be `get` or `post`

In the password example I already authed so I am just passing the token so i can get something.

Your `argscollection` is a structure...so you can loop over it.

the `requestOject` is a normal structure of common expected things in the cfhhtp call the name and the matching `argsCollection` value (and then the type of parameter)

```
<cfhttp url="#url#" 
    method="#method#" 
    result="response" 
    username="#AccountID#" 
    password="#AuthToken#">

    <cfloop collection="#argscollection#" item="v">
        <cfhttpparam name="#parameterTarget(v, requestObject)#" 
                     value="#argscollection[v]#" 
                     type="#fieldType#"  />
    </cfloop>

    </cfhttp>

<cfdump var="#response#">
```

I'm sure this will shake a few more 'possibilities' free from your mind. Or inspire another CFHTTP expert to chime in...

Also if this is a common library you are pulling from/talking to, then consider [RIAForge](http://www.riaforge.org/), [CFLib](http://www.cflib.org/) or GitHub because chances are there is a Coldfusion wrapper already built and waiting for you there.

Answer (score 0):

the $remoteArray did have an error in it. Originally the $apiauthkey, $apicomponent and $apimethod were defined outside of the array. Once they were added into the array for json encoding it worked.